# JSON stringify not including fields added to object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a JSON object where I need to append the fields `bioDescription` and `bioPicUrl`  to the object before I `JSON.stringify()` the data. I can add the fields and it outputs the to the screen as a JSON object as seen in output below.

OUTPUT

```
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     OUTPUT
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     _id: 5e907943a9a0e12b90b178c9,
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     title: 'test',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     startingBid: '10.00',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     increments: '15.00',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     shippingCost: 'Free Shipping',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     auctionType: 'publicAuction',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     creator: 5e9076fc2da43424e8e3df82,
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     __v: 0 },
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]   bioDescription: 'testtt',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]   bioPicUrl: null ]
```

but when I `JSON.stringify()` the data, the bioDescription and bioPicUrl fields are not included. I tried adding `|` delimiter as something I can use `.split("|")` function and add `,` to, but it doesn't parse right and I feel like there's an easier way lol. I appreciate any help!
How can I get the data to append and stringify together?

```
  .then(documents => {

                documents.bioDescription = artistBioResults.bioDescription;
                documents.bioPicUrl = artistBioResults.bioPicUrl;

                output = JSON.stringify(documents);
             //   output = output + "|" + bioDescription + "|" + bioPicUrl;

                console.log("OUTPUT");
                console.log(documents);
```

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: what is the issue ?? unclear explanation :/

Comment: Where do you actually print `output`? Also, we are not seeing the full output. Your print ends with `]` suggesting a list. Please make a reproducible example.

Comment: The issue is that the bioDescription and bioPicUrl fields don't get stringified with the rest of the JSON data. I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/xgt2aq9h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines give it away. Note the `},` and the `]`

```
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]     __v: 0 },
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]   bioDescription: 'testtt',
[4/10/2020 3:59:23 PM]   bioPicUrl: null ]
```

You are adding the attributes to an array of documents, not each document in the collection. Try this...

```
documents.forEach(doc => {
    doc.bioDescription = 'test';
    doc.bioPicUrl = null;
});
```

OTOH, if you are actually trying to add properties to the whole array, JSON.stringify() will ignore them since there is no way to put array properties into JSON syntax.

The solution is to wrap theses other properties in an object that includes your array. The following javascript has a JSON representation that wont drop the properties you're interested in keeping.

```
{ documents: [], bioDescription: 'test', bioPicUrl: null }
```

Comment: I don't think forEach solution will work because I'm not trying to append it to each row. I'ts not always one documents. It could be up to 5 docs before adding ```bioPicUrl``` and ```bioDescription```. I want it to be it's own row of data that I can use on the frontend. This is that I can store the same JSON obj into a redis cache and retrieve it together. I also tried ``` documents.push(['bioDescription', artistBioResults.bioDescription]);
documents.push(['bioPicUrl', artistBioResults.bioPicUrl]);```, but it returns 2 null rows instead of the data in the new rows. https://postimg.cc/bDc3C8ZW

Comment: There's your problem. Arrays can have properties in javascript but not in JSON. I updated my answer to address this scenario.

Comment: This worked nicely. Thanks for the suggestion! https://jsfiddle.net/f56Labku/

Answer (score 0):

`documents` is an array.

You can't do this with an array:

`documents.documents.bioDescription = something`